# I am not able to view mp3 files on my sansa clip player that were previously loaded using windows

Tags: windows, mp3-player, sansa-clip

I have added the file .is_audio_player and still no luck.  Any Suggestions?

In Ubuntu 12.04, when I connect mp3 player, the home folder opens and I can see files that I have added to the player since I started using Ubuntu, however any music/podcasts/audiobooks that I put on the player when I was using Windows do not show at all. They do not show in Rhythmbox either.  Ubuntu will recognize the mp3 player in msc but not in mtp.

Comment: When you plug in the Sansa Clip to USB, does a Nautilus Window **not** open and show you the folders? Or is it that you can't view the mp3 files in the mp3 player like Rhythmbox?

Comment: the home folder opens and I can see files that I have added to the player since I started using Ubuntu, however any music/podcasts/audiobooks that I put on the player when I was using Windows do not show at all.  They do not show in Rhythmbox either.

Comment: Please edit your original question with the additional information.  Also indicate if the Sansa clip is using [MTP or MSC mode](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/162/~/mtp-or-msc). You may try to change the mode from MSC to MTP or vice versa and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks user68186, i have updated the original question.  I tried MSC and MTP and no luck.  I cannot see the files under MSC and the player is not recognized under MTP.

Comment: I will say that I had the same problem, but ended up just dealing with the Sansa exclusively on Ubuntu....

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with files not appearing when my device was connected to my PC. (Sansa 240)

I initially attempted to select "Show hidden files" in my File Explorer options setting, but that was already selected.

Further Googling then lead me to the Sandisk website where I learned about the USB mode (connectivity) problem. It says that I should switch to the MSC mode on my device, then connect to my PC. When I checked, MSC was already selected but there was another option called Auto Detect, which I selected. When I connected to my PC, my folder view instantly changed and I was finally able to see my music files (and delete unwanted ones). So it was not actually the MSC mode that I needed, but I learned that I had to "unselect" it in order to view my Sansa files on the PC. Go to Settings on your device, and there should be a USB setting you can adjust.

Try this option and see how it goes. Here is the link.

https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/447/~/songs-show-up-and-play-on-the-sansa-player-but-does-not-show-up-on-the-computer